# precipitation reaction - cellulose in schweizer reagent reacts with acid

Tags: transition-metals

In the regeneration of dissolved cellulose (in a cuprammonium solution) in an acid bath, say sulphuric acid, what is the chemical reaction?

There is a lot about the chemistry of the production of the copper ammonia complex but nothing about the precipitation step.

Is the precipitation possible with any acid?

Apologies about the tag - can't find any existing ones that are appropriate

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to regenerate cellulose from Schweizer's reagent [by dilution in plain water](http://textilelibrary.weebly.com/cuprammonium-rayon-mfg-process.html), though neutralization of the high pH+ cuprammonium solution with an acid is more efficient. $\ce{HCl}$ works as well as $\ce{H2SO4}$. Economics probably drives the choice.

The chemistry is based on breaking cellulose, a [polysaccharide (polymer)  β(1→4) linked D-glucose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose), into smaller, soluble, segments, and reconstituting the longer polysaccharide through neutralization.